# Is this proof rigorus?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Simple abstract algebra proof:

> Suppose that $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $a$ and $b$ relatively prime. If $a|bc$, then $a|c$.

**Proof 1**

Since $a$ & $b$ relatively prime, $a|bc\Rightarrow a|c$ since $a\nmid b$. $\square$

I feel this is too short. Maybe the next one would be better?

**Proof 2**

Since $a$ & $b$ relatively prime, we have $ax+by=1$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$. Multiplying through by $c$ gives $acx+bcy=c$, so if $a|bc$, then $a$ divides both terms of $acx+bcy$, so $a|c$. $\square$

What do you think?

Comment: Its a bit short because its not right, $(b,c) = 1$ and $a|bc$ only implies $a|c$ or $a|b$; no where do we know a does not divide $b$. But it can't divide both (else there would be a common factor).

Comment: Yes but if $a$ and $b$ relatively prime then their $gcd=1$. Therefore one cannot be a divisor of the other.

Comment: Otherwise their $gcd$ would be the divisor, i.e $a$ and they are now not relatively prime.

Comment: Proof 1 is wrong. Especially the remark 'since $a\nmid b$' is incorrect. Proof 2 is excellent.

Comment: @drhab Would you be able to explain why proof 1 is wrong?

Comment: Reasoning like: $4\mid2\times6$ so $4\mid6$ since $4\nmid2$ is incorrect.

Comment: @drhab Why don't you post the your two comments as an answer. I deleted mine, since I think you've done a better job of nailing it.

Comment: @amWhy Okay, I will do that. Thank you.

Comment: @George1811: To understand why proofs are correct or wrong and not just depend on intuition or vague understanding, write out everything formally. In the case of "divides", don't leave it as $a|bc$ but write "$bc = ak$ for some integer k". Now if you claim that "$b \neq am$ for any integer m", you can see why it does not follow that "$c = an$ for some integer n", and so $a\not|b$ is not enough, as others have pointed out.

Comment: However $4$ and $6$ are not relatively prime. I'm confused how if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, then all the prime factors of $b$ are not the thing that $a$ divides, therefore $a$ must divide a factor of c therefore $a|c$

Comment: @George1811: You didn't prove that "all the prime factors of b are not the thing that a divides". Are you able to formally specify what "not the thing..." means? If you are then you can then use it to prove the result, which is not at all the same as writing "$a \not| b$".

Comment: Isn't it the definition of relatively prime? They have no common prime factors. Therefore $a$ cannot divide $b$ as then they both have the common factor $a$. I should have explained myself a lot better I realize that now, I'll use proof 2 from now anyway :)

Comment: @George1811 $a$ and $b$ relatively prime does not imply that $a\nmid b$. For instance $1$ and $2$ are relatively prime and $1\mid 2$. Relatively prime means that no prime $p$ exists with $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$. Based on that you can reason that from $a\mid bc$ it follows that all primefactors of $a$ must be primefactors of $c$ and consequently $a\mid c$. But proof 2 has definitely more elegance.

Comment: The argument in Proof $1$ is not *complete* since you have not deduced the desired result from the hypotheses. Rather, you deduced only that $\,a\nmid b\,$ (and you overlooked your case $\,a=1).\ \ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proof 1 is wrong.

The remark 'since $a\nmid b$' is incorrect.

Reasoning like: ...$4\mid2\times6$ so $4\mid6$ since $4\nmid2$... is incorrect.

Also note that from the fact that $a$ and $b$ being relatively prime it cannot be concluded that $a\nmid b$. For instance $1$ and $2$ are relatively prime and also we have $1\mid2$.

Proof 2 is excellent.

Comment: Well done drhab! (+)

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for the encouragement :-)

Comment: But he added since a & b are relatively prime,so basically the reasoning is correct.

Comment: @kingW3 In proof 1 it is indeed mentioned that $a$ and $b$ are coprime, but it remains unclear how that is used. In fact the OP makes strongly the impression to use it wrongly (i.e. no full exploitation of it), by only saying that 'since $a\nmid b$'. I would not accept it as a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Proof 1 doesn't fully employ the fact that *a* and *b* are relatively prime, only that $a \nmid b$. For a counter-example $a = 9; b = 3; c = 6$ Here $a \nmid b$ and $a \mid bc$ but $a \nmid c$.

Proof 2 is good.

Comment: Point of interest: Since $a$ & $b$ relatively prime, we have $ax+by=1$ for some $x,y∈Z$ is called *Bézout's Identity*